# Flux Actions to Redux Actions Conversion

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, flux, reactjs-flux

Hi I have an action setup but its in flux, and I need to refactor it to match with Redux actions.

Any help would be highly appreciated with migrating both to redux.

Comment: What is your actual question? Can you edit your question to only show one example of an action you have in flux, and how you're doing it in redux, and the problem you're having?

Comment: @AndyRay So I am converting from flux to redux and how do I use my bind functions as in this reducer with redux? Anad how would I go about this.emit("change") in redux?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering your questino from the comments;

> How do I use my bind functions as in this reducer with redux? Anad how would I go about this.emit("change") in redux?

In redux, you connect your component to the Redux State as follows:

```
ReduxEnabledComponent = ReactRedux.connect(
    function(state) {
        return {
            someProp: state.someProp
        },
    {
        someAction: function(){
            return {type: 'action_type', data: {}}
        }
    }
)(Component);
```

The above code would take a component named `Component` and connect it to the Redux Store.  This component would receive props of `someProp`, which is a value of the Redux Store, as well as `someAction`, which is a method to use for emitting a request to the store.